# Unit tests failing on a remote server with IPC error

Tags: java, ipc, jxmaps

While trying to use JxMaps in my project I ran into the following error :

```
com.teamdev.jxmaps.internal.internal.ipc.v: IPC process exited. Exit code: 139
    at com.teamdev.jxmaps.internal.internal.ipc.p.run(SourceFile:185)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

After a lot research I came up short finding anyone with the same problem (closest was exit code 127 which I've had before and fixed)

Code that causes this is any code that uses JxMaps, even the simplest

```
MapView mp = new MapView();
```

Would love any help I can get

edit : forgot to mention this is on ubuntu xenial x86_64

Comment: Best I could tell this is caused because the remote server doesn't have display which chromium requires, but ideally I should still be able to run it as I still need data from it even without the display part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers :
The solution in the end was both of the following :

Install xserver

```
sudo apt-get install xorg openbox
```

Install ubuntu-desktop

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

As a result I'm getting a different error, and am now looking for a solution to that.
error is :

```
com.teamdev.jxmaps.internal.internal.ipc.v: Failed to get Browser browserChannel 0
```

if and when I will find a solution I will update here

**UPDATE** :

The solution turned out to be setting a fake display using :

```
sudo startx -- :1
```

and defining `DISPLAY` environment variable to be `:1`